# Rails nested resource ID isn't relative to the parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a small Rails 5 application that has boards, and each board has posts (sort of like Reddit).

Board model:

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 64}
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I have nested the post resource under the board resource.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :boards, param: :name, path: '/' do
    resources :posts, path: '/', except: [:index]
  end
end
```

rails routes:

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    board_posts POST   /:board_name(.:format)          posts#create
 new_board_post GET    /:board_name/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_board_post GET    /:board_name/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     board_post GET    /:board_name/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                PATCH  /:board_name/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                PUT    /:board_name/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                DELETE /:board_name/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
         boards GET    /                               boards#index
                POST   /                               boards#create
      new_board GET    /new(.:format)                  boards#new
     edit_board GET    /:name/edit(.:format)           boards#edit
          board GET    /:name(.:format)                boards#show
                PATCH  /:name(.:format)                boards#update
                PUT    /:name(.:format)                boards#update
                DELETE /:name(.:format)                boards#destroy
```

The problem I have is that the post IDs are incremented globally, not relative to the board it's posted on. An example:

Let's say I have two empty boards: a 'news' board and a 'politics' board. I create a post for the news board and get the route:
`http://localhost:3000/news/1`. Great, this is what I expect. It's post #1 on the board so the post ID should be 1. Now my issue is that if I make a post to the other board, the post gets the ID 2 as in: `http://localhost:3000/politics/2`. I want it to be `http://localhost:3000/politics/1` because it's the first post relative to that board.

How can I achieve this, so that the IDs are relative to the parent board?

Answer (score 0):

My hint: Do not do this, this is very error prone.

But if you really need this you can use code like this:

```
Board.find_by(name: params[:board_name]).posts.first(id).last
```

Please keep in mind it will load all posts associated with given board into memory, so if your board have million posts the performance can be an issue.